# Should sayings within a quote be set apart by single quotes, italics, or in some other way?

Tags: quotes, italics

In the following quote:

> “We try not to be overly flashy when taking solos,” band leader
> Ricardo said. “The principles that come to mind are ‘don't blow all
> your cookies in the first bar’ and ‘keep it simple, smarty-pants’ —
> when we adhere to those concepts, we see (and hear) the benefits.”

... should the two "principles" be single-quoted (as they are above), or italicized, as below:

> “We try not to be overly flashy when taking solos,” band leader
> Ricardo said. “The principles that come to mind are *don't blow all
> your cookies in the first bar* and *keep it simple, smarty-pants* —
> when we adhere to those concepts, we see (and hear) the benefits.”

... or ...???

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. There is no rule, as far as I know.

Comment: If you say they are *principles*, not quotes, you are not quoting them, and italics looks good.

Comment: The short answer is: Consult your editor. If you have no editor, do whatever you think is best. If you don't know what's best, why are you writing?

Comment: @Yosef If they're reasonably non-trivial and someone else (or even you yourself on an earlier occasion) came up with them, arguably they're quotes every time they're mentioned.  But there are quotes and quotes (not to mention the superscripted commas).

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm not the writer, I'm the proofreader / quasi editor. I did, though, alter what was written so as not to divulge the true nature of the paragraph.